# How to use distinct, count and sum simultaneously in the SELECT field?

Tags: mysql

I have created a table with the columns: **departments**, **NumberOfEmployees** and **Salary**
I would like to apply a `DISTINCT` on the first column, a `COUNT` on the second and a `SUM` on the last.

My query being:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.department_name as departments, e.employee_id as NumbOfEmployees, e.salary as Salary
FROM departments d
INNER JOIN employees e
ON d.department_id = e.department_id
ORDER BY departments
```

This query will result in the following table:

```
department | numbofemployees | salary
----------   ---------------   ------
Accounting | 205             | 12000
Accounting | 200             | 5445
Admininstr.| 100             | 51651
Executive  | 101             | 100000
Executive  | 102             | 100000
Executive  | 103             | 100000
```

**note: numbofemployees is now the employee ID number.

I would like to create the following table:

```
department | numbofemployees | salary
----------   ---------------   ------
Accounting | 2               | 17445
Admininstr.| 1               | 51651
Executive  | 3               | 300000
```

Comment: Please read up on aggregate functions, post a code attempt here when you have done so.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html - or wait for someone to give you a solution.

Comment: It's almost never necessary to use `DISTINCT` when using aggregation functions and `GROUP BY`, since there will never be a duplicate of the column(s) you're grouping by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT d.department_name as departments, 
       COUNT(*) as NumbOfEmployees, 
       SUM(e.salary) as Salary
FROM departments d
INNER JOIN employees e
ON d.department_id = e.department_id
GROUP BY d.department_name
ORDER BY departments
```